# sed: adding a new line between strings

Tags: bash, sed, ls

I am using the combination of the ls + sed to make a list of the images in the folder and create output file of scpeficic format where each line separated by the empty line etc

```
ls ${blocks}/*png | sed 's/^/![caption](/;s/$/)\n/' > ${blocks}/out
```

The problem is that, inspite of the \n in the end sed does not add a "new line" after each string.

also would it be better to use find instead of ls for big number of png images?

Comment: The newline characters are added here with `GNU sed 4.7`. What `sed` do you use? Note: using `ls` for scripting is not recommended.

Comment: Please read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing output of `ls` can be error prone and must be avoided. Moreover bsd `sed` doesn't interpret `\n` as newline like you're using and emits a literal `n` in the substitution.

However, you don't even need `ls | sed` here, just use this for loop:

```bash
for f in "$blocks"/*.png; do
   printf '![caption](%s)\n\n' "$f"
done > "$blocks"/out
```

Or better just `printf`:

```bash
printf '![caption](%s)\n\n' "$blocks"/*.png
```

Comment: Or `printf '![caption](%s)\n\n' "$blocks"/*.png`, no loop at all.

Comment: it works! may it be piped to something to the processed PNG files according the alphaphetic order of its names ?

Comment: You can pipe it like this `xargs -I {} process_png {} < <(printf '%s\n' "$blocks"/*.png)` where `process_png` is the command to process png files.

Comment: okay, thank you ! it's not fully clear I am going to make a new topic .. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
find "$blocks" -type f -name '*.png' -printf "![caption](%p)\n\n"
```

Comment: actually with -printf the created document is empty .. it adds just n in the end of the line as it was with the sed. I am on mac OSX using bash 4

Comment: Strange. It works like a charm here, under macOS, `bash` 3.2 or `bash` 5.2.15(1)-release, with `find (GNU findutils) 4.9.0`. Try maybe with single quotes instead of double quotes (but as your `sed` command already uses single quotes I doubt it will change anything). With single quotes it also works under `zsh 5.9` and the same find.

Comment: Could it be that, as most utilities, your default `find` is so old that it does not interpret `\n` as newline but as regular `n`? What do you see if you type `find --version`? Note: if you work under macOS you should consider installing recent versions of all utilities with [macports](https://www.macports.org/) or [homebrew](https://brew.sh/). The versions that come by default are sometimes extremely old for licenses reasons.

Comment: okay I gotcha. btw the version with the loop of png filles proposed above works very well :-)

Comment: @JamesStarlight Sure. But shell loops are much slower than what a recent `find` would do. Moreover `find` can search the whole hierarchy while it is getting more difficult with shell loops. But of course, if you have a small number of files and they are all in the same directory, a shell loop is fine. Last but not least, with a recent `find` you can use the `-exec` action to process the found files on the fly.